# Converting rpy syntax to rpy2 syntax

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Assuming I have successfully imported rpy2 (which I have), what other modules/packages from rpy2 do I need to import (and other syntax changes where needed) in order to convert the following strings of rpy version 1.x functions to its rpy2 equivalent?  I can no longer use rpy 1.x in the environment I am operating under for python 2.7.3 and need to convert these to work with rpy2 get my code to work:

```
rpy.r.assign(rName, values) #get name, assign value
rpy.r.get("variablename") #get variable names
rpy.r.source (sourceloc + "sourcelocation") #source location
rpy.r.rm(list=rpy.r.ls()) #clean workspace
rpy.r.attach(rpy.r.get("fun")) #attach function
rpy.r.setwd(os.getcwd()) #set working directory
rpy.r.save_image() #save workspace image
rpy.r.load("filename.RData") #load an .RData file
```

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you would need to define the Python variables `rName`, `values`, `sourceloc`, etc. The only other change you would need is

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
R = ro.r
```

and change every occurrence of `rpy.r` to `R`:

```
R.assign(rName, values) #get name, assign value
R.get("variablename") #get variable names
R.source(sourceloc + "sourcelocation") #source location
R.rm(list=R.ls()) #clean workspace
R.attach(R.get("fun")) #attach function
R.setwd(os.getcwd()) #set working directory
R.save_image() #save workspace image
R.load("filename.RData") #load an .RData file
```

Comment: doesn't work?  If you load up python IDLE and import rpy2robjects as ro, then R = ro.r.  Then if you type R followed by "." and wait for the drop down list, there isn't a get, assign, rm, attach, etc.  So the environment variables have completely changed for rpy2 from what I can tell.  PS--I am working in Windows enviro.

Comment: There are so many R functions that instead of defining each one as an attribute of `ro.r`, `rpy2` uses the `__getattribute__` (and `__getitem__`) methods to look up the values as needed. So even though you do not see them in IDLE, they do exist. Instead of waiting for the dropdown list, try typing `R.assign` and pressing `Enter`. It should return a `SignatureTranslatedFunction` object.

Comment: (correction: I shouldn't imply that `__getattribute__` is used just because of the number of attributes; it's also used because they are all defined the same way: through calls to `_globalenv.get` and `conversion.ri2py`. The unfortunate drawback is that you won't see them as attributes when using an IDE with autocompletion.)

Comment: Well I get a return object, which is good... but my script is still failing. Agree that the lack of autocompletion is unfortunate.  Forgot how much I relied on that feature to check to make sure packages were installed.  :)